# basic python file IO homework

Tags: python, file-io

I'm having trouble figuring out where I'm going wrong here.

The original file is:

```
python is a programming language that lets you WORK more quickly and integrate your systems more effectively. 
you can learn to use python and see almost immediate gains in PRODUCTIVITY and lower maintenance COSTS. 
it's very helpful for any field of study.
```

I'm trying to create a function that takes a file and reads it and then capitalizes the sentences, changes the caps lock to lower case and the "it's" to "this is". Then put the file back together and add a period after the sentences. Write the new file string into a .txt file named 'Edited.txt.

My code is:

```
 def edit(aFile):
   f = open(aFile, 'r')
   xs = f.readlines()
   f.close()
   g = open('happy.txt', 'w')
   for x in xs:
     x.capitalize()
     if x.isupper==1:
       x.lower()
     g.write(x)
   g.close()
```

The error I get is "File not found-happy.txt(Access is denied). I tried to read the file and couldn't.

I am 100% positive that the file is there and the media path is set to the folder.

Comment: We'd be better able to help you figure out why it isn't working if you mentioned what sort of errors/wrong output you're getting

Comment: try adding this in the begining of the script, "import os; print os.path.abspath(os.curdir)". See if you are in fact running this in the same directory, or maybe it's running in the python local directory.

Comment: It is running in the local directory. How do I change that? I've been doing setMediaPath()

Answer (score 2):

```
isupper
```

is a method that returns True or False, so the line should read:

```
if x.isupper():
```

not

```
if x.isupper==1:
```

Not sure if this answers your question, but you should really post more about the error for us to answer properly.

Additionally, many of the python string methods, such as capitalize() and lower() create COPIES of the string, and don't actually modify the original string. So if:

```
x = "TEST"
```

then calling

```
y = x.lower()
```

will result in x still being "TEST" and y being "test".

Comment: Sorry I'm having a lot of trouble understanding calling the file and writing to the file

Comment: Perhaps you should go through each line of code that you've written and figure out exactly what it does. For help with a specific function/method, you can consult "docs.python.org", or you can search, for example, "python file open" on a search engine to figure out what exactly things do. This will probably make your problem fix itself.

Answer (score 0):

This statement doesn't do anything as is:

```
x.capitalize()
```

It returns `x` with the first character capitalized, but you don't save the results anywhere.  Also, x remains unchanged after this statement.  If you want to capitalize the first char of `x`, do this:

```
x = x.capitalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first major mistake that I can see is that you are doing string methods without assigning them to anything.  Strings are immutable, so `x.capitalize()` does nothing (as jh314 said).

In addition to what the others have said, your `for x in xs` line is saying "for every line in the file, do the following".  Your file appears to only be one line, so you are trying to do everything on one line.

Try looking at the documentation on regular expressions and string methods.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

They should be helpful for identifying the places within your line that you would like to modify.